# Android studio 2.3.2 pinch to zoom on Mac not working

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio 2.3.2 pinch to zoom (Increase or decrease the font size using trackpad) on Mac not working. I am facing this problem from last two month it is so frustrating, I thought it will be fixed in 2.3.2 but it has not fixed.

is there any alternative solution?

**Solution:**

As soon I asked this question, I found the solution. Hope this will help others.
https://medium.com/@jsuch2362/android-studio-pinch-to-zoom-fix-temporary-7bfd05c72a2b

Comment: It always has worked on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64552235/how-to-enable-editor-pinch-to-zoom-in-android-studio) for a workaround. It is fixing issue but you must use Command button with two fingers sliding downward or upward to zoom in or out. I use it too.

Answer (score -3):

go to application

select android studio and show package content

select content folder and then select macOs folder

and finally replace studio file by downloading from this site and  make it executable

http://tools.android.com/knownissues/studio