# How to enable Editor pinch to zoom in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, pinchzoom

As a Mac user, you can pinch to zoom the editor in Android Studio because is based on IntelliJ.

But I can't do that anymore in the latest Android Studio version (4.1)

I've already tried:

- checked Change font size with Command + Mouse Wheel in Editor > General
- checked actionSystem.mouseGesturesEnabled in Android Studio Registry

No luck at all.

Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: What is the solution?  I am wondering the same.

Comment: Currently, None. A friend of mine also has Android Studio 4.1 and the feature works perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried to write to the support? Is there any official ticket?

Answer (score 3):

I have found a way to Zoom in Android Studio 4.1.1 in macOS 11.1.

- open Settings with cmd+,
- on search field in top left corner write: mouse
- select Editor -> General
- in Mouse Control area select: Chance font size with Command+Mouse Wheel
- click in OK Button

[General Editor Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwKWl.png)

After this configurations I was able to zoom pressing cmd+two fingers on trackpad.

[]'s

Comment: MacOS 11.1 That's the key point. I'm on 10.5

Comment: I test on macOS 10.13.6 and it works, so cmd+two fingers to zoom does not depends on macOS but Android Studio. Try it on your system.

Comment: My mistake in the previous comment. My MacOS version is 10.15.4 and I also tried your solution. No luck but I really appreciate your effort. (y)